# Multiple Private repo cocoapods spec file

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods, specifications

I submite my code to github and creat cocoapods spec filestrong text

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "PageSegment"
  s.version      = "v0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "A short description of PageSegment."
  s.description  = <<-DESC
  这是一个关于承载多个页面的聚合页，并且可以自定义top栏每个item的样式
                   DESC
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/sunhua163/PageSegment"
  s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "FILE_LICENSE" }
  s.author             = { "sunhua" => "sunhua@yizijob.com" }
  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/sunhua163/PageSegment", :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.source_files  = "Classes", "PageSegment/PageSegment框架/**/*.{h,m}"
  s.exclude_files = "Classes/Exclude"
end
```

When I do pod spec lint . I get

```
pod spec lint
 -> PageSegment.podspec
    - ERROR | spec: The specification defined in `PageSegment.podspec` could not be loaded.
[!] Invalid `PageSegment.podspec` file: Malformed version number string v0.0.1.
 #  from PageSegment.podspec:19
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    
 >    s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/sunhua163/PageSegment", :tag => s.version.to_s }
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------
Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error.
[!] The validator for Swift projects uses Swift 3.0 by default, if you are using a different version of swift you can use a `.swift-version` file to set the version for your Pod. For example to use Swift 2.3, run: 
    `echo "2.3" > .swift-version`.
```

Can anybody please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following command in the terminal:

```
`echo "2.3" > .swift-version`
```

It will create a swift version file in your pod-project folder. And then you can run the lint command to validate your podspec.